# Change asterick's position when declaring a pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I try to declare a pointer in Visual Studio 2019, the asterisk shifts to the pointer's type side.
I know this works, but it irritates me.

```
// How it shows:
int* number1{};

// How i want it to show: 
int *number2{};
```

Is there a way I can change that?

Comment: Did you search through the settings for the one that you want? Should only take a few minutes. By the way, the left-aligned way is far superior to yours. :)

Comment: I did searched, but couldn't find a option that can disable this

Comment: There's gotta be one, and you must have turned it on - I don't encounter this at all on my VS 2019 and I reset it to factory recently. Don't have it in front of me atm though.

Comment: @J.Doe thanks a lot, that fixed it !

Comment: @NicolaeCiobanu You're welcome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please have a look at the available options in menu [Tools] -> [Options] -> [Text Editor] -> [C/C++] -> [Formatting] -> [Spacing] -> [Pointer/Reference alignment].